# finding the integral solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that the equation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^{-2} = 1$ has integral solutions for $n > 6$.

I have no idea how to proceed, can someone give me a hint.

Sorry for the mistakes in the text above.

Comment: Where is n in question

Comment: oh sorry ! I for to put a n over sigma.can you please do it for me,I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Thank you!

Comment: To put something in subscript/superscript, put a `_` or `^` in front of it. Bracket that thing by `{}` if that contains more than one token.  eg.  `\sum_{i=1}^n`

Answer (score 3):

For $n=7$, take $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=4$ and $x_5=x_6=x_7=2$

For $n=8$, take $x_1=x_2=2$, $x_3=x_4=x_5=x_6=3$ and $x_7=x_8=6$

For $n=9$, take $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=x_6=x_7=x_8=x_9=3$

Now suppose we have a solution $x_1, x_2$ . . . $x_n$ for some $n$. Then:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i^{-2}=1$

So, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(2x_i)^{-2}=1/4$.

Therefore, $2x_1, 2x_2$ . . . $2x_n, 2, 2, 2$ becomes a solution for case of $n+3$. As the problem has been solved for $n=7,8,9$, by induction, we have a solution for all $n>6$.